# ErrorException Undefined property: mysqli::$kd_max

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I was trying to make unique code based on date,

Here's my Model for creating the unique code :

```
public function get_kode()
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(RIGHT(kode_list,4)) AS kd_max FROM list_produksi_toko");
    $kd = "";
    if($q->getResult() > 0){
        foreach($q as $k){
            $tmp = ((int)$k->kd_max)+1;
            // $kd = sprintf("%04s", $tmp);
            $kd = sprintf("%'.04d", $tmp);
        }
    }else{
        $kd = "0001";
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    return date('ym').$kd;
}
```

it wont work and show error just like in the title, but if i change this :

```
if($q->getResult() > 0){
```

to this :

```
if($q->getResult() < 0){
```

It work, but it keep showing "20090001" the same code even after i input it to database.

What can i do to make it generate unique code, like if "20090001" is already exist it will make "20090002"

Comment: With the change to `if($q->getResult() < 0)`, it “works” — *cough* doesn’t throw an exception *cough* — because it _doesn’t run_ the problematic code and instead executes `$kd = "0001"`. Yet the _code that is skipped_ contains the logic which is supposed to generate the next value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
public function get_kode()
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(RIGHT(kode_list,4)) AS kd_max FROM list_produksi_toko");
    $kd = "";
    $result = $q->getResult();
    // try to use $q->getRow(); to get single row and reduce the code of **for loop**
    if(isset($result)){
        foreach($result as $k){//change
            $tmp = ((int)$k->kd_max)+1;
            // $kd = sprintf("%04s", $tmp);
            $kd = sprintf("%'.04d", $tmp);
        }
    }else{
        $kd = "0001";
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    return date('ym').$kd;
}
```

Comment: for better code, you need to see this [ https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows ]